# Selecting random 'featured' articles amongst recent articles using MySQL, with fallback if none exist

Tags: mysql

this is a slightly tricky one to explain so I'll try to list out what I'm trying to achieve:

1. I'm outputting news articles on a page, ordered by most recent first.
2. Some articles are marked as 'sponsored' in the database.
3. In a row of 4 articles, I'd like to include up to 2 sponsored to appear randomly (i.e. not fixed positions)
4. The sponsored articles are not date sensitive, so they can be from any time.
5. If there are no sponsored articles found, I'd like to just display the 4 most recent articles.

So far, I've attempted one query to achieve this, using UNION to group 2 different results and then order the whole lot randomly.

My current query is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM articles
        WHERE sponsored = 0             
        ORDER BY publish_at DESC 
        LIMIT 2
)
UNION
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM articles
    WHERE sponsored = 1   
    ORDER BY RAND() 
    LIMIT 2
    )
) TEMP
ORDER BY RAND()
```

This works nicely when there are 2 sponsored articles, however if there are none, I only end up with 2 most recent articles (as the query would suggest).

Does this sound possible within one query, or should I be looking to add some conditional PHP and further queries (which I was trying to avoid)?

I'm aware I might be approaching this in completely the wrong way, so open to suggestions for alternative methods!

Comment: I have no idea whether this would work but the first thing that occurred to me might be to query the sponsored articles first, with a `COUNT(*) as recurrence` and use `4 - recurrence` to determine the limit on the other articles ... something something nested queries something... not really thought it through yet :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select 4 organic articles, and so potentially you select up to 6, then you can filter down from there. It might be easier to do some of this in PHP, as this can get a little convoluted, but this will work.

Assuming a table structure like:

```
CREATE TABLE
`articles`
(
  `article_id` INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content` TEXT,
  `sponsored` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0,
  `publish_at` DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO
  `articles`
(`content`, `sponsored`, `publish_at`)
VALUES
('Article 1', 0, '2018-06-25'),
('Article 2', 0, '2018-06-25'),
('Article 3', 0, '2018-06-25'),
('Article 4', 0, '2018-06-25'),
('Article 5', 1, '2018-06-25'),
('Article 6', 1, '2018-06-25'),
('Article 7', 1, '2018-06-25'),
('Article 8', 1, '2018-06-25');
```

You can do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      `articles`
    WHERE
      `sponsored` = 0
    ORDER BY 
      `publish_at` DESC
    LIMIT 4
  ) AS OrganicArticles
  UNION
  SELECT * FROM
  (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      `articles`
    WHERE
      `sponsored` = 1
    ORDER BY 
      RAND()
    LIMIT 2
  ) AS SponsoredArticles
  ORDER BY 
    `sponsored` DESC
  LIMIT 4
  ) AS AllArticles
ORDER BY
  RAND()
;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0138f0/11

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Exactly what I was looking for :)